# Callback handling in Google Drive API NodeJS Sample

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api

I am exploring google drive integration with NodeJS, and using the sample code:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs

When you check this sample code, listfiles is passed as a callback in the Oauth2 authorization flow. I am quite new to Javascript, and trying to figure out how to access the data returned from drive API (files.list) async call into the main app.js. I have require the myModule in the app.js and invoking the auth function which is calling the authorization flow and invoking listfiles function in the callback after OAuth2 flow.

Problem: I was able to list the files but not sure how to an handle of the data returned in the callback.

Solution: I was able to pass another function as callback which can be called in listfiles.

Comment: Please don't use stack snippets for code that's not meant to be run in the browser.

Comment: I am a bit novice JS developer, so trying to get help. I will delete the stack snippets after getting some help. Thanks.